# Determine if the following matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, similar-matrices

> $$A= \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc|c}
>   5&3&\sqrt2\\
>   0&1&0\\
>   0&0&5\\
> \end{array}
> \right) , \qquad B= \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc|c}
>   5&0&0\\
>   0&1&0\\
>   0&0&5\\
> \end{array}
> \right) , \qquad C= \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc|c}
>   1&0&0\\
>   3&5&0\\
>   \sqrt2&0&5\\
> \end{array}
> \right) $$ The correct answer is that $B$ and $C$ are similar.

---

First, I checked the trace of each matrix

$$ \mbox{tr} A=5+1+5=11, \qquad \mbox{tr} B=5+1+5=11, \qquad \mbox{tr} C=1+5+5=11 $$

Then, I checked ranks and got $\mbox{rank}(A)=\mbox{rank}(B)=\mbox{rank}(C)=3$. Then, also for determinants

$$\det(A)=\det(B)=\det(C)=25$$

Then, the characteristic polynomial

$$\det (\lambda I -A)=\det (\lambda I -B)=\det (\lambda I -C)= (\lambda-5)^2 \cdot (\lambda-1)$$

- $\lambda = 5$: algebraic multiplicity = 2, geometric multiplicity = 2
- $\lambda = 1$: algebraic multiplicity = 1, geometric multiplicity = 1 (because the algebraic multiplicity of 1 is 1)

My conclusion is that all of them are similar and not just $B$ and $C$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct. Yes, matrices $B$ and $C$ are similar. But the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalues $5$ is only $1$-dimensional in the case of matrix $A$ (it is spanned by $(1,0,0)$); in other words, the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $5$ is $1$ in the case of matrix $A$. But it is $2$ for $B$ and $C$.